# Python. Фото скачивается, но оно сломано

Tags: python, requests

Python. Фото скачивается, но оно сломано, то есть вместо изображения знак сломанной картинки. Что делать?
Код:

```
import requests
url = "https://thiscatdoesnotexist.com/?1582681489783=1/document.jpg"
res = requests.get(url).content
with open(url.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0], 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res)
```

Comment: Проблема не в коде, а в картинке.

Comment: @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica В коде.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

При `res = requests.get(url)` код ответа `520`. Это значит, что на удалённом сервере произошла какая-то внутренняя ошибка.

---

Первая догадка: сервер не ожидал в заголовке `User-Agent` увидеть значение `python-requests/2.22.0` (такой `User-Agent` отправляется по умолчанию, если его явно не указали). Можно попробовать отправить `User-Agent` какого-нибудь браузера. Например, `Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36`

```py
res = requests.get(
    url, 
    headers={
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.3987.122 Safari/537.36"
    }
)
```

В таком случае код ответа `200`. Это говорит о том, что всё хорошо. Можно записывать `content` ответа в файл

```py
with open(url.split('/')[-1].split('?')[0], 'wb') as f:
    f.write(res.content)
```

Answer (score 1):

Добавьте заголовок `User-Agent`.

***Пример:***

```py
import requests


URL = 'https://thiscatdoesnotexist.com/?1582681489783=1/document.jpg'
HEADERS =  {
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/79.0.3945.136 YaBrowser/20.2.3.213 Yowser/2.5 Safari/537.36',
}


def main():
    photo = requests.get(URL, headers=HEADERS).content

    filename = URL.split('/')[-1]
    with open(filename, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(photo)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```